# Module parse failed: Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. @splinetool/runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, spline

I am using a react portfolio template. I am new to react and webpack. I am trying to use Spline to add a 3D model to my page, but I'm getting the following error.

```
./node_modules/@splinetool/runtime/build/runtime.js 19847:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (19847:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| function fI(r, e) {
|   var t = typeof r; >   return e = e ?? hI, !!e && (t == "number" || t != "symbol" && dI.test(r)) && r > -1 && r % 1 == 0 && r < e;
| }
|
```

I have also installed **react-script** package and **typescript** which are required for spline to work.

**My package.json file:**

```
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/",
  "basename": "/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@splinetool/react-spline": "^2.2.1",
    "@splinetool/runtime": "^0.9.73",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "1.6.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.7",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.7",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.7.1",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.6.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^3.3.3",
    "react-animate-on-scroll": "^2.1.5",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-countup": "^4.3.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-iframe": "^1.8.0",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.1",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.6",
    "react-parallax": "^3.1.2",
    "react-particles-js": "^2.7.1",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scroll-up": "^1.3.5",
    "react-scrollspy": "^3.4.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.24.0",
    "react-tabs": "^3.1.1",
    "react-text-loop": "^2.3.0",
    "react-tilt": "^0.1.4",
    "react-video-tag": "0.0.10",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "resolve": "1.10.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "semver": "6.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.2",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack": "4.29.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.6",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

**Part of my React code:**

````
class SliderOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
 <div className="slider-activation">
<div className="inner">
<Spline scene="https://prod.spline.design/zijR8dif6Kg3gTyC/scene.splinecode" />
</div>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my version of **node js was in 12.x.x**, I **changed to 16.x.x** and everything works